# What information about the factors of a big number can be gained in a couple of minutes?

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization, computational-mathematics, big-numbers

Given a number with some hundreds of decimal figures, it's possible to check

- if it is a prime number
- if there are small factors
- if there are factors close to the square root.

But what else? Are there other information, relevant for factoring, that can be obtained fast with a personal computer?

Comment: Software tools I prefer : PARI/GP for not too difficult calculations, yafu (for factoring) and pfgw (for primality testing). Magma Online calculator is also nice, but you have to program a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no known algorithms to determine efficiently the number of distint prime factors, nor the approximate size of the smallest factor. The check-list usually is : trial division , primality test , p-1-test , ECM and finally SIQS , if the number is not too big.

Answer (score 3):

If the number is not too big, the best current known algorithm is the quadratic sieve. Numbers upto about $120$ digits can be factored this way (With some more effort upto about $150$ digits).

To find factors upto about $30-40$ digits, the elliptic curve method (ECM) is best and does not depend on the size of the number.

In rare cases, the $p-1$-method gives large factors.

Primality checking can be done much more efficient. Very good tests include the Miller-Rabin and the BPSW-test. If we want to prove the primality , this is also routine upto about $1\ 000$ digits.

Comment: For the BPSW-test , NO example is known where it fails although infinite many should exist. It is claimed that upto at least $2^{64}$ , the test is always valid.